# Page View Counter like on StackOverFlow

Tags: asp.net

What is the best way to implement the page view counter like the ones they have here on the site where each question has a "Views" counter?

Factoring in Performance and Scalability issues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The counter i optimized works like this:

```
UPDATE page_views SET counter = counter + 1 WHERE page_id = x
if (affected_rows == 0 ) {
   INSERT INTO page_views (page_id, counter) VALUES (x, 1)
}
```

This way you run 2 query for the first view, the other views require only 1 query.

Comment: One of the challenges here is either a) the potential for serialization or b) a race condition - depends on your transaction isolation level.

Comment: Right, one of the worries we have is possibly a race condition. Should this be done asynchronously ?

Comment: @stephbu : for your b) it's more a non-critical race conditions because increasing of +1 doesn't change if a query is done in same time... +1 +1 or +1 +1 equal always +2.

Comment: you could of course insert a row for every new page and set the counter to 0

Comment: @daok like I pointed out it depends on where your transaction boundaries are and how tolerant of race conditions you can be.

Comment: @stephbu this wont be a problem for the question the user asked.

Comment: @daok I'm not sure I agree there - he asked to factor in scalability - serializing all the calls by experience is not very scalable.  You'd need to pair it with other solutions e.g. async updates to enable to workaround the serialization.

Comment: I think I do not follow you with your serializing... What are you talking about?

Comment: I used this at it works great, thanks man. I suggest you do it in stored procedures form though.

Answer (score 11):

I've made two observations on the stackoverflow views counter:

- There's a `link` element in the header that handles triggering the count update.  For this question, the markup looks like this:
  `<link href="/questions/246919/increment-view-count" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />`
  I imagine you could hit that url to update the viewcount without ever actually viewing the page, but I haven't tried it.
- I had a [uservoice ticket](http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/general/suggestions/33016), where the response from Jeff indicated that views are not incremented from the same ip twice in a row.

Comment: fyi for those reading this later - I'm pretty sure they've changed this since the original post.

Comment: seems like a nice idea - keep the counter in a cacheable resource, so that it will only get incremented the first time the resource is 'loaded'. Beats cookies & sessions for simplicity.

Comment: @tucuxi Do you know how to know when the resource is loaded and when not? Thanks

Comment: @oscar If it hits your server, then it is being loaded. The interesting part is that repeat views of the page will avoid downloading a resource that "has not changed"; this means that there will be no new requests arriving at your server until the cache is emptied.

Comment: This approach is not very efficient because I could clear my cache and hit the counter again, clear my cache another time and hit it again, ad infinitum..

Answer (score 6):

An efficient way may be :
Store your counters in the Application object, you may persist it to file/DB periodically and on application close.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of making a database call everytime the database is hit, I would increment a counter using a cache object and depending on how many visits you get to your site every day you have send the page hits to the database every 100th hit to the site. This is waay faster then updating the database on every single hit.

Or another solution is analyzing the IIS log file and updating hits every 30min through a windows service. This is what I have implemented and it work wonders.

Comment: I like your solution better. I came here looking for a solution to avoid hitting DB every time.

Comment: Have you got any example or documentation for your solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an IHttpHandler to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of @Guillaume's style of implementation.  I use a transparent GIF handler and in-memory queues to batch-up sets of changes that are then periodically flushed using a seperate thread created in global.asax.

The handler implements IHttpHandler, processes the request parameters e.g. page id, language etc., updates the queue, then response.writes the transparent GIF.

By moving persistent changes to a seperate thread than the user-request you also deal much better with potential serialization issues from running multiple servers etc.

Of course you could just pay someone else to do the work too e.g. with transparent gifs.

Answer (score 0):

For me the best way is to have a field in the question table and update it when the question is accessed

```
UPDATE Questions SET views = views + 1 WHERE QuestionID = x
```

Application Object: IMO is not scalable because the may end with lots of memory consumption as more questions are accessed.
Page_views table: no need to, you have to do a costly join after

Comment: @Eduardo being practical even with 10m pages - you're still only talking about at most 10m ints - I think I burn through 50Mb just cracking open the CLR ;)  Memory is cheap - serialization isn't.