# Page View / Post View Counter

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a post view counter, so far its easy, but i have following problem, when user reloads the page it gets updated again, i want track only raw, but not the reloads. How i could make this best? setting a cookie?

The the site: the site has over 10k+ posts, im not sure, if this done with a cookie would work :)

And about updating the DB, should i do it in realtime with update low priority, or saving the data and processing like every 5 mins?

Gimma please some input how i can make this. Thank you

Comment: I found a good solution:

i log ip + post id in an array after 5 mins i call a script which updates the DB and with ARRAY_UNIQUE i filter duplicates out, not the best solution but should work for me thank you for you inputs :)

Comment: use session_id also or else if people are accessing from same office then you will get only one visit per office

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the unique user by comparing ip | session Id | page Id if the combination of same value exists then don`t insert it or insert it but process later by taking unique values

Answer (score 0):

You can work it with the cookie, like setting a cookie var UPDATED to 1 if the hit have been updated.
  But the problem with COOKIE is anyone can edit it, so you can also try it with SESSION as user can not edit it.
 DB is not a good option i think, You can try Google Analytic too

Comment: SESSION is linked to COOKIE; if the user erases cookies, session is also lost.

Comment: i said no one can edit session, i tried to mean 'NO ONE CAN CHANGE THE VALUE in the SESSION THEM SELF'

Comment: they would not be able to change the value in your 'UPDATED' cookie either, because you would only check whether it existed or not (after all, UPDATED=100 can never mean 100 unique visits). So in this case, the only possible sort of 'edit' is 'delete'.

Comment: if you got FIREFOX then please try **COOKIE MANAGER**, with it you can do whatever you want to with a _COOKIE_

Comment: I meant 'possible' as 'will make a difference in count', not 'possible' as in 'can be altered by client'. Yes, cookies can be changed. Also, don't use ALL-CAPS when writing comments.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer, suggested from [Page View Counter like on StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246919/page-view-counter-like-on-stackoverflow/24722), is to

- add a 'token resource' in your page header, such as `<link href="/questions/246919/increment-view-count" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />`. Notice that the token resource should be page-specific (due to path), and that all modern browsers cache the resource files that they download.
- only increment your counter when the token resource is downloaded anew (you can use apache's mod-rewrite to keep tidy urls that then map to whatever incrementing counter you have). This avoids the need for cookies or storing [ip | session | page] for each pageview, cutting down on the number of database requests; and avoids the need for cookies.

It is just as safe as an [ip | session | page] combination agains attack (in either case, someone can write a tight loop requesting the resource-or-page without storing cookies). But there is no safe-fail way to avoid abuse while counting all requests (because of NAT, you can not rely on unique IPs for everyone).