# How to implement a hit counter in MEAN stack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

**QUESTION:**

How can I implement a hit count on each post a user makes ?

The count should increase for each unique visitor that views the page.

I know how to increase the count and save it server side, but how can I limit it by IP and prevent manipulation ?

P.S.: I would prefer not to use GA (Google Analytics) for this.

---

**REFERENCE:**

This mentions using the cache. Could someone explain how this would look in javascript ?

[Page View Counter like on StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246919/page-view-counter-like-on-stackoverflow)

Comment: Question is far too broad. This isn't a *"how to"* tutorial service

Comment: @charlietfl Your understanding of my question differs from mine but I respect that ^^

Comment: I honestly appreciate the question, unlike the unsurprisingly full of ego users of this place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One options is to create a document for the id of the post and the IP of the user, to ensure unique visitors. This could look like this:

```
var hitSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  postId: STRING,
  ip: STRING
});
```

After a few entries this document would look like this:

```
[{
  postId: 1,
  ip: 192.168.0.1
}, {
  postId: 1,
  ip: 192.168.0.2
}]
```

Now, when you do a get request for a post, check if the IP has been logged for the post and and add it if it has'nt.

```
app.get('/api/posts/:id', function(req, res) {
  var postId = req.params.id;
  var ip = req.connection.remoteAddress;

  Hit.find({postId: postId, ip: ip}).then(function(result) {
    //var newVisitor = false;
    if (!result) { /* add a new record and newVisitor = true */

    return Post.find({id: postId}).then(function(post) {
      //if (newVisitor) { /* update the counter on the post */
      res.send(post);
    });
  });
});
```

Now, what we have accomplished now is a unique value for all the visitors. You can then either query the document and get a list of IP that has visited to get the count, or add a counter on the `Post` object with the new IP, and then increment this  if it's not found.

The last options is normal when you need to increase the efficiency for the algorithm.

Comment: I am not sure I understand: I would have to create a document for each IP hit consisting of postID and IP to know if it was hit before ? This seems very inefficient :/

Comment: You would have to make sure that the visitor (IP) is unique to the list of visitors to a single post (postId). or else you will increase the counter every time someone refreshes the page.

Comment: Your reasoning is absolutely sound but I am just wondering if there isn't a simpler answer ? For example what is discussed here ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246919/page-view-counter-like-on-stackoverflow I am not sure though :/

Comment: Imagine you want to show a list of posts ordered by their views. For this you would want to 'denormalize' the count value so you dont have to do the lookup for all posts all the time by adding a counter on the `Post`. But to make sure the counter records unique visitors. You need to know previous visitors and that is what the hit document is ment for.

Comment: I understand your solution and used something similar for other elements in my model, but I am also specifically looking  to understand how the solutions expressed here work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246919/page-view-counter-like-on-stackoverflow

Comment: For example, what do you think of this :

Comment: "Instead of making a database call everytime the database is hit, I would increment a counter using a cache object and depending on how many visits you get to your site every day you have send the page hits to the database every 100th hit to the site. This is waay faster then updating the database on every single hit.

Or another solution is analyzing the IIS log file and updating hits every 30min through a windows service. This is what I have implemented and it work wonders."

Comment: How would the windows service work ? Wouldn't the cache solution be simply countered by clearing the cache before each view ?

Comment: I am looking for the best solution :)

Comment: I consider how Windows Servers and IIS works is outside the scope for express/node. All data stored in memory is lost if the server stops, and you could possible get an out of memory exception. If all you want is a hit counter in memory you could store this in an object. `var visited = { 'postId': 'counter', 'postId': 'counter'}`

Comment: Thank you for your analysis and your answer :D